# Do mov or lda set flags in 8085 assembly?

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, 8085

I want to check if C register is empty before doing any computations with that register(other than moving the data we got from somewhere to it.)

```
LDA 8100H;
MOV B,A;
JNZ MOVE;
```

Can I use `JNZ` after `MOV` to check if B is zero or not? Because if the value is zero then I should return 0 and end the program(the program is multiplying two values without using the `MUL` function. I am adding B to A B times to multiply these two numbers. we did this program at school but my teacher didn't check if the initial value was zero.  He checked if it was zero after decreasing the counter.)

Comment: 1. 8085 and 8086 are different processors. Which one are you targetting? 2. What does the instruction set reference say regarding status flags updated by `MOV`?

Comment: Yes, it's a definite RTM situation. If you don't have your instruction table handy, get it now.

Comment: Where can i find one from?

Comment: Page 3-35 and 3-36 of one of the [instruction set references](http://www.tramm.li/i8080/Intel%208080-8085%20Assembly%20Language%20Programming%201977%20Intel.pdf) for the 8085 has `Flags: none` for the `MOV` instruction, which means flags are unaffected by a `MOV`

Comment: Google is always a good start, but @MichaelPetch has you covered.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I tried finding one but no resource mentioned flags.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
LDA 8100H
ORA A
MOV B,A
JNZ MOVE
```

Move instructions do not change the flags as these fall under the Data Movement instructions.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you commented the code to explain that ORA A *does* set flags according to the value of `A`, and the `LDA` doesn't.